Read from config using batch
Here is a code from one of my batch files with variables inside it.
@echo off

REM -----choose coder-----------
set "coder=h264_nvenc"

REM ----Chose bitrate (3,5,8 etc)--------
set "bitrate=3"

REM ---Shoose fps (25,30,50,60)----
set "fps=30"

REM ----audiobitrate (96, 128,192,256,312)---
set "audiobitrate=128"

REM ---Audio samplerate (44100, 48000)-----
set "sampler=48000"

for %%i in (1.ishodniki*.mov,1.ishodniki*.mp4); do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -codec:v %coder% -b:v %bitrate%M -filter:v fps=30 -codec:a ac3 -b:a %audiobitrate%K -ar %sampler% "2.segments%%~ni.mp4"

@pause

i want to read the variables from config file, not from batch file
I created a config.txt,
it has structure like this
-----choose the coder (libx264 or h264_nvenc)-----------
coder=libx264

----Choose bitrate(3,5,7 etc)--------
bitrate=3

---the name of the listfile---
list=list.txt

How should I read from the config.txt and how to use these variables inside of my batch

Based upon your example file content, @For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "=" 0^<"P:\athTo\config.txt" 2^>NUL') Do @Set "%%G", will probably cover it.

This is something you could try, it goes thru a for-loop reading all the variables name, so it filters for everything in front of the "=" in each txt line, and creates a varible with the same name.
In the second for-loop, it then reads the value from the same line after the "=" symbol, theoretly you can also now create new variables just by expanding your txt file.
REM create the variables
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims== skip=2" %%A in (config.txt) do (
    set "%%A=%%B"
)

REM Fill the variables
for %%i in (%list%) do (
    ffmpeg -i "%%i" -codec:v %coder% -b:v %bitrate%M -filter:v fps=%fps% -codec:a ac3 -b:a %audiobitrate%K -ar %sampler% "2.segments%%~ni.mp4"
)

You might however want to include something, to check if all your required variables have been read correctly, to insure that the script doesnt crash randomly. This is how to do that:
if not defined VariableName (
    echo womp womp
    pause
    exit /b
)

